# How to download receipt and invoice from stripe through my site

Tags: codeigniter, stripe-payments

I am using stripe from payment. After payment using invoice id how can i download receipt and invoice from my site

Comment: Sir what you have tried so far , show some code details

Comment: I am using subscriptions in my site for every month the new invoice will create. How can user download that invoice

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask